# anyone knows how to make this cone tent in blender?

Tags: modeling

i got difficulty when making a cone shaped tent.
it is a combination of square and cone, i think.
i have tried so many times to make it but still far from the actual shape.
[image]

[image]

Comment: please click on "accept answer" so other users although know that the answer helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You basically start with a plane.
Subdivide it using an odd number (Like 29)
Select the center vertex, use proportional editing in "Sharp" mode and pull the vertex up along the Z axis.
Select the outer vertices and extrude them down the Z axis.
[image]

You can also do this with a 4 sided cone which will make it a bit more realistic.
[image]

Comment: This way geometry gets stretched, not sure this is the right approach

Comment: I guess the cool approach would be to use cloth simulation. Anyway, we can always remesh I think.

Comment: could be, but might be an overkill for this object and also remesh is not great

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating an 8 sides circle (move up) and a plane (4 sides)
connect them manually - three vertices from the circle to one plane edge.

extrude the bottom of the plane and create a loop cut in the middle of the edge - the loop cut won't go all the way up, you will have to connect the middle vert on the circle to the new edge using J.

now you will be able to add a loopcut across the faces, use LoopTools to circle the loop cut and scale it down a bit.
add few more and scale a bit more until you get the desired result.

this is what I got:
[image]

You can now collapse the top circle to one vertex or leave as is and just cap it and add a bevel and a subdivision modifier.

Result:
[image]

Comment: wow! i understand now.

Comment: thank you guys for your help. i feel like i'm really falling in love with blender that it literally can make ANYTHING.